# API controller in MVC App not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have created an mvc application with SSO. I have added an Api controller, but whenever i try to get data from it, i get error.
URI= https://localhost:44305/api/graph/get

Error:
Server Error in '/' Application.
 The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /api/graph/get
Here is my Route config

```
public class RouteConfig
{
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "Default",
        //    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Graph", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

This is my web api controller

```
public JsonResult<List<Claim>> Get()
{
        var principal = (User as ClaimsPrincipal);
        List<Claim> claimsList = new List<Claim>();
        foreach (var claim in principal.Claims)
        {
            claimsList.Add(claim);
        }
        return Json<List<Claim>>(claimsList);
}
```

Not getting any build error. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @Stefan browser shows "server error "/" in application". The resource cannot be found

Comment: Can you see the http address which is being requested?

Comment: Try opening the Windows `Event Viewer` application and take a look at `Windows Logs\Application`. You should see any ASP.NET related errors appear in there, which might give you a hint as to what the problem is with your site.

Comment: @Stefan no its writing Requested url:graph/get

Comment: why have you set the `api` routes in the `MVC` route config and not `WebApiConfig.cs`?

Comment: @Ric because i have created the mvc app. web api is not there. What i did was In mvc app, right click controllers->new controller->empty web api controller

Comment: have you tried `api/graph/get` ?

Comment: @GeneR yes i have tried that too

Comment: if i am not wrong it should be GET request and can be url `api/graph`

Comment: @Ric This time i have tried to create a WebApiConfig.cs and map route in that but still same error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the URI you use to visit the API, and the actual error it shows.

Comment: @CodeCaster done the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have 2 config files:

> RoutesConfig.cs and WebApiConfig.cs

RoutesConfig should look like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        Log.Instance().Debug("Registering Routes");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs should look like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ConfigureRouting(config);
        ConfigureFormatters(config);
    }

    private static void ConfigureFormatters(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new NiceEnumConverter());
    }

    private static void ConfigureRouting(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, @namespace = "api" });
    }
}
```

Within global.asax.cs you should have something like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // Register them in this order
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Configure); //registers WebApi routes
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);  //register MVC routes
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Your controller does look a little strange why not let the default serialiser take care for things for you:

```
public IEnumerable<Claim> Get()
{
        var principal = (User as ClaimsPrincipal);
        List<Claim> claimsList = new List<Claim>();
        foreach (var claim in principal.Claims)
        {
            claimsList.Add(claim);
        }
        return claimsList;
}
```

EDIT: removed redundant code

Answer (score 2):

Hy Guys.Thanks for all your help. I have figured out the solution. The answer is that in Global.asax.cs,

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)
```

has to be called before

```
 RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes).
```

Comment: Seriously you had the answer twice above.  Probably should have just put a comment in

Comment: @jolySoft please read carefully. My problem was that i was calling route config before globalconfiguration. And i have tried to help others who may have same problem

Comment: If you had a problem with global.asax.cs please edit your question to include this with the error in it.  This also would be helpful to give concise answers.  Thanks you

Comment: @jolySoft i was not aware of the problem in global.asax.cs before. Thats why i posted it here. And i thought it will be better to post an answer rather than telling answer in question itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    }
}


public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultDataApi",
            routeTemplate: "Api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}


public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have made changes to global.asax.cs as well

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name of your controller is GraphController, I think the url you should be using is /api/graph/get.

If it's named something different, you'll need to adjust the url accordingly.

Also, there's a separate .cs file in MVC projects you should use to manage WebAPI routes - WebApiConfig.cs